# csrf token missing in django ajax post request working using get request

Tags: django, datatables

I am working with metronic datatables in which i have a file where ajax function works. The problem is that when I use type in ajax function "GET" it works but in POST it does not work and it gives CSRF token missing error in console, but in case of GET it does not give any error, I am using django framework for my site and my ajax function is :-

```
"ajax": { // define ajax settings
    "url": document.URL, // ajax URL
    "type": "POST", // request type
    "timeout": 20000,
    "data": function(data) { // add request parameters before submit
        $.each(ajaxParams, function(key, value) {
            data[key] = value;
        });
        Metronic.blockUI({
            message: tableOptions.loadingMessage,
            target: tableContainer,
            overlayColor: 'none',
            cenrerY: true,
            boxed: true
        });
    },
}
```

urls.py file is :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^logout$', views.logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^dashboard$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^profile$', views.profile, name='profile'),
    url(r'^edit-profile$', views.edit_profile, name='edit-profile'),
    url(r'^check-password$', views.check_password, name='check-password'),
    url(r'^help$', views.faq_management, name='help'),
    url(r'^testing$', views.testing_database, name='testing'),
    url(r'^add-faq$', views.add_faq, name='add-faq')
]
```

view related to this function is :

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from models import Admin, Help
from django.contrib import messages
from django.utils.html import escape
from .forms import ImageUploadForm
import json
from datetime import datetime

def faq_management(request):
if 'admin_id' in request.session:
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if request.is_ajax():
            ajax_data = request.GET
            if ajax_data['length'] !=-1 :
                limit = ajax_data['length']
            else :
                limit="all"
            questions = Help.objects.all().filter().values('id','question','description','status','created','modified').order_by('-id')
            datalist = []
            i=1;
            for que in questions:
                if(que['status']=='1'):
                    checked='on'
                else:
                    checked='off'
                actionValues='<a title="Edit" class="btn btn-sm green margin-top-10" href=""> <i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>';
                inner_data_list = [
                    i,
                    que['question'], 
                    (que['description'][:150] + '..') if len(que['description']) > 150 else que['description'],
                    '<div id=%s class="bootstrap-switch  bootstrap-switch-%s  bootstrap-switch-wrapper bootstrap-switch-animate toogle_switch"><div class="bootstrap-switch-container" ><span class="bootstrap-switch-handle-on bootstrap-switch-primary">&nbsp;Active&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><label class="bootstrap-switch-label">&nbsp;</label><span class="bootstrap-switch-handle-off bootstrap-switch-default">&nbsp;Inactive&nbsp;</span></div></div>'%(que['id'],checked),
                    que['created'],
                    que['modified'],
                    actionValues
                ]
                datalist.append(inner_data_list)
                i += 1  
            iTotalRecords=questions.count()
            iDisplayLength = int(ajax_data['length']);
            iDisplayStart = int(ajax_data['start']);
            if iDisplayLength < 0 :
                iDisplayLength = iTotalRecords
            sEcho = int(ajax_data['draw'])
            records = {}
            records['data'] = {}
            records['data'] = {}
            records['data'] = datalist
            records['customActionStatus'] = {}
            records['customActionMessage'] = {}
            records['draw'] = {}
            records['recordsTotal'] = {}
            records['recordsFiltered'] = {}
            if request.GET.get('customActionType', '') == 'group_action':
                records['customActionStatus'] = 'OK'
                records['customActionMessage'] = 'Group action successfully has been completed. Well done!'
            records["draw"] = sEcho
            records["recordsTotal"] = iTotalRecords
            records["recordsFiltered"] = iTotalRecords
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(records, default=json_serial))

        admin = Admin.objects.get(pk = request.session["admin_id"])
        return render(request, 'admin/faq-manage.py', {
            'adminInfo': admin,
        })
else:
    messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'ERROR! Kindly login first.')
    return redirect(index)
```

Comment: show me your `urls.py` and function in `views.py` related that ajax function

Comment: I have shown view and file in question

Answer (score 1):

You don't get error with `GET` because CSRF tokens are required only for `POST` requests.

Check out this topic in the docs - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/

Comment: Yes I know, But i have to run it for post request, that's why its giving me error csrf token missing.

Comment: Read the link I posted. It explains how to pass the token via ajax. There are other ways too, but you'll get the idea. Other answers on SO provide different approaches.